# Mailkit unexpected disconnection from server when downloading headers from Yahoo Mail

Tags: imap, mailkit

I am trying to fetch IMAP headers from **Yahoo Mail**. It works fine when I try to grab the first 100 headers but it disconnects when I try to get the headers of all 32,000+ emails. I get an exception saying that "The IMAP server has unexpectedly disconnected".

I tried using **Gmail** to grab up to 19,000 headers and it works fine.

Any ideas or is there any limitations? I have included the protocol log here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6109m1ii113af0c/protocollog.txt?dl=0

Comment: Usally that means a server bug and it tripped over a certain message.  Do you have the log from where it disconnects?  And what it did just before that?

Comment: Fetching 32,000 UIDs in one go is likely to overflow the servers line buffer.  RFC 2683 suggests limiting command lines to about 1000 characters, which is about 200 per request.

Comment: I could not add more comments so moved the comments to chat

Comment: The entire chat is here in case it helps someone: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193288/discussion-between-samuel-and-jstedfast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade your MailKit. The problem is probably that your list of UIDs is too long causing your IMAP server to disconnect.

The latest version of MailKit will break apart the list of UIDs into multiple duplicate commands with smaller subsets of the UIDs in order to avoid creating a command-line that is too long for the IMAP server to handle.

Comment: Yes, the new version breaks up the UID request command. So in my case, it sent 1200 UIDs so the server responded by sending 1200 FETCH response. But after that it again got disconnected! Now it gives the error - S: C00000008 NO [UNAVAILABLE] UID FETCH Server error while fetching messages

Comment: can you link a new protocol log?

Comment: Here is the log... https://www.dropbox.com/s/riqlzy5pxir05uo/protocollog2.txt?dl=0

Comment: The [UNAVAILABLE] response code is supposed to be used when the server is unable to complete the request due to a resource being temporarily unavailable. So it's either that or the yahoo mail is buggy, not sure which.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that with Gmail (19000+ headers) now it is taking about 40 seconds to download headers compared to about half of the time before. Maybe it is network speed but I will investigate further.

Comment: Well, that's not surprising because it has to send more commands now (since it is breaking apart the really long command into a bunch of smaller ones).

Comment: If you can tell me how long the original GMail command-line was, I can try to bump the allowable command-line length for GMail.

Comment: Interesting thing is that it gave the error message after the server sent all the headers that were requested in the first pass.

Comment: I agree, that is puzzling that it sent [UNAVAILABLE] after it completed the command. Hence why I think it is just a bug in the server.

Comment: I do not have the previous log right now. I can downgrade the mailkit and test it again. Current version is 2.1.5.1, can you tell me what I should downgrade to test this?

Comment: trying with 2.1.4

Comment: You'll need v2.1.3. Try to get the full command line length starting with the "A000###" tag. I suspect it's probably within 16k.

Comment: I am unable to add more comments: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193288/discussion-between-samuel-and-jstedfast).